# Multiprocessing threadpool close with timeout

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'd like to gracefully stop pool workers with the pool object's `close()` method, but `terminate()` those that don't finish execution in 10 seconds.

```
started_at = int(time.time())
p.close() # this is blocking
if (int(time.time()) - started_at >= 10):
  p.terminate()
```

Something like this. Any idea? :)

I also thought about sending `SIGTERM`s to the threads, but they share the same pid, so I can't do this.

Comment: sorry, it's ThreadPool in my case. fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a threadpool, you could use a global variable (e.g. `stopthreads`).

The function(s) running in the worker threads should inspect this variable often and exit when it is set to `True`:

```
def worker(data):
    while True:
        if stopthreads:
            return None
        # do other things
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I didn't get the question the first time.

You maybe can send the `p.close()` call to another process, using `apply_async` for example, and see if the `apply_async` call doesn't finish in time, just call `p.terminate()`.

For more info on `apply_async` reference the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).